# How I can get the number of the user that follow me in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How I can get the number of the users that follow me, not whose I follow them

This get the users that I follow them

```
account = Account.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        view_account = account
        my_account = Account.objects.get(username=request.user)
        if view_account in my_account.following.all():
            follow = True
        else:
            follow = False

        followers = view_account.following.all()
        number_of_followers = len(followers)
```

How I can get the opposite, The numbers of users whose follow me

The Account model

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
    verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True
)
following = models.ManyToManyField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="follow"
)
```

Comment: Please share your `Account` model.

Comment: This also will show the number of people `view_account` is following, which is likely another account than `my_account`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is *not* a good idea to work with `len(…)` here, since that will fetch all `followers`, and then only obtain the number of followers, this is inefficient use of the bandwidth between the database and the Django/Python layer.

You can count the reverse relation with:

```
num_followers = view_account.follow.count()
```

and the number of useers the `view_account` is following` can be retrieved with:

```
num_following = view_account.following.count()
```

Comment: Supposedly a user has millions of followers, should I still do this, won't it become inefficient, what should I do in those cases?